# pandas compare two different size dataframe mapping values and adding an arbitrary value when ones is missing

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, merge

Trying to learn pandas and I am applying it to a problem I was solving with various loops with standard python/php tools.

Say I have two dataframes like this, df1 is smaller than df2 and for ClientApplication values in df2 there might not be a corresponding SubProgram in df1

```
df1

ClientApplication Subprogram
insert_data       AA1
remove_data       AB1
update_data       XX0

df2

Time       ClientApplication Duration Result
2020-01-01 insert_data       300      error
2020-02-01 insert_data       100      ok
2020-03-01 update_data       1000     ok
2020-06-02 remove_data       50       error
2020-07-01 check_data        0        ok
```

I need to achieve a few things:

- add a column for Subprogram in df2 with the value that correspond
  to the same ClientApplication in df1.  When there isn't a
  correspondance found in df1 add an arbitrary value ('Unknown')
- add the missing ClienApplication values in df1 with Subprogram
  value set to an arbitrary value of 'Unknown'

I can get what I want with a merge using the on condition, I know I can achieve this with a map as well, but I can't find a way to manage the missing values by adding the arbitrary string 'Unknown' when that's the case besides making other manipulation afterwards based on NaN values, so I can't see the most compact and efficient way to achieve this in pandas.

df1 is a small dataframe with less than a 1000 rows while df2 will be in the millions.

df1 is constructed from a SQL query while df2 is constructed from a csv, the df1 table will need to be updated as the csv come in with all the newly identified Unknown ClientApplication and df2 will be imported in a db with the added column and updated values, this is unrelated to the task but it might impact in choosing the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: If any questions helped or solved the problem, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :-)

Comment: sorry I haven't been working on the problem, I do it in my spare time. I tried some solutions and none do exactly what I want but they pointed me toward the proper way to achieve what I need, I will reply to everybody and post a working solution asap

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, first let's create the dataframes:

```
from io import StringIO
content = """ClientApplication Subprogram
insert_data AA1
remove_data AB1
update_data XX0
"""
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(content), sep=" ")
print(df1)
  ClientApplication Subprogram
0       insert_data        AA1
1       remove_data        AB1
2       update_data        XX0
content = """Time ClientApplication Duration Result
2020-01-01 insert_data 300 error
2020-02-01 insert_data 100 ok
2020-03-01 update_data 1000 ok
2020-06-02 remove_data 50 error
2020-07-01 check_data 0 ok
"""
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(content), sep=" ")
print(df2)
         Time ClientApplication  Duration Result
0  2020-01-01       insert_data       300  error
1  2020-02-01       insert_data       100     ok
2  2020-03-01       update_data      1000     ok
3  2020-06-02       remove_data        50  error
4  2020-07-01        check_data         0     ok
```

Ok, now merge:

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='right', on='ClientApplication', )
result
ClientApplication   Subprogram  Time    Duration    Result
0   insert_data AA1 2020-01-01  300 error
1   insert_data AA1 2020-02-01  100 ok
2   remove_data AB1 2020-06-02  50  error
3   update_data XX0 2020-03-01  1000    ok
4   check_data  NaN 2020-07-01  0   ok
```

and now you can use **.fillna()** to "set to an arbitrary value of 'Unknown'"

```
result.fillna("Unknown")
ClientApplication   Subprogram  Time    Duration    Result
0   insert_data AA1 2020-01-01  300 error
1   insert_data AA1 2020-02-01  100 ok
2   remove_data AB1 2020-06-02  50  error
3   update_data XX0 2020-03-01  1000    ok
4   check_data  Unknown 2020-07-01  0   ok
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a new column in df2, use `map` with `fillna`

```
s = df1.set_index('ClientApplication')['Subprogram']
df2['Subprogram'] = df2['ClientApplication'].map(s).fillna('Unknown')

#result df2
    Time        ClientApplication   Duration    Result  Subprogram
0   2020-01-01  insert_data         300         error   AA1
1   2020-02-01  insert_data         100         ok      AA1
2   2020-03-01  update_data         1000        ok      XX0
3   2020-06-02  remove_data         50          error   AB1
4   2020-07-01  check_data          0           ok      Unknown
```

The simplest way i found to add the new values in df1 was to redo df1 using `drop_duplicates` in df2 (which i believe is faster than `merge`, maybe you can test to prove?! :-) )

```
df1 = df2[['ClientApplication', 'Subprogram']].drop_duplicates()

#result df1
    ClientApplication   Subprogram
0   insert_data         AA1
2   update_data         XX0
3   remove_data         AB1
4   check_data          Unknown
```